# How to resize objects for different screen sizes using auto layout on Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I need to make simple application fit in different iPhone screens such as iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6/6s, iPhone 6 Plus (see image below).

[image: app preview]

The view controller has two views in it. The top view (grey area), which contains buttons and labels. The bottom view (white area), which contains 10 image views, 9 apples and a plate.

Is it possible to resize the objects in each view proportionally according to the screen size using the auto layout?

I only need to do this for iPhone Screens in Portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

For top view is a good idea - use `UICollectionView`.
A digit - it's a `UICollectionViewCell` with `UIImageView` as subview. For this cell you have to return size :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat size = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)/5.0;
    return CGSizeMake(size, size);
}
```

So, for `0 + 1 = ?` the same logic. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Layout constraints has "constant" and "multiplier". You can use multiplier for your purposes

Comment: for your purposes*